# Swift, bottom constraint while in-call status bar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set a view fixed to the bottom. However, when an in call status bar appears, the view is pushed down.

My constraint looks like this:

```
let bottomHolder = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height-100, width: screenSize.width, height: 100))
bottomHolder.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
let bottomHolderConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bottomHolder, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
self.view.addSubview(bottomHolder)
self.view.addConstraint(bottomHolderConstraint)
```

Answer (score 0):

Review your constraints. If you have vertical spacing to top layout guide then go to vertical spacing to superview (View). If you have bottom space to bottom layout guide then go to bottom space to superview (View).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnUvO.png)